# How do I get the SQL command text when I insert a new record with Linq?

Tags: linq, insert

```
var newUser = new tblUser() { 
    Email = strEmail,
    Password = strPassword,
    DateBirth = DateTime.Parse(strDateBirth),
};
db.tblUsers.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I want to get the actual SQL query that linq generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext.Log property to a writer, you can wrap a writer around a stringbuilder then after your insert response.write your stringbuilder.tostring...

```
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
                Context.Log = writer;
                ...
                    DOINSERT & SUBMITCHANGES
                ...
                Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

db.Log is a TextWriter that you can use to get the text of the query.

```
db.Log = Console.Out
var newUser = new tblUser()
{ 
    Email = strEmail,
    Password = strPassword,
    DateBirth = DateTime.Parse(strDateBirth),
};
db.tblUsers.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

And it will write the query text to standard output.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Why Console.Out? I'm using ASP.NET, it's a web app, I think I need response.write to output.
I also tried to use Response.wirte but it prints nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx). You can use `DataContext.Log` property.